# How to make eclipse automatically add spaces between operators and operands?

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting

How to make eclipse automatically format my code as I type?

Example:
I want eclipse to change

```
a+b==0
```

to

```
a + b == 0
```

**on the fly**.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the settings to automatically format the code when saving. For Java code, for instance, go to **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Save Actions**. In that page, there is an option to format source code on save. By default, the Eclipse built-in formatter is configured to add spaces between operators and operands.

You can also manually format the code by pressing the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: No way to make Eclipse do it on the fly as I press enter after errorless line? Some IDE's do that...

Comment: @MaxSegal AFAIK, no. You can also check http://superuser.com/questions/329577/formatting-in-eclipse.